# onChange returns a callback while using setState in reactjs antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, antd

I am using antd input and while I am trying to update the state using onChange the focus to the input disappear on each letter, i have to focus the input again and again to complete a word. 
Please help me i am so much frustrated.

```
class IndexMain extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      username: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist()
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value })
  }
render() {
 return(
  <div>
    <Input
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      value={this.state.username}
    />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is ok. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I tried out your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6zzo2qqjnr and it seems to be fine.

Comment: Something outside of this component must be contributing to the problem.

Comment: **yes, Something outside of this component was troubling me. Thanks a lot for all you people's support.**